# What's the difference between esc printer cut command full cut and half cut,?

Tags: android

My thermal printer cuts the same way in both occasions.Can some one explain what a full cut and what's half cut and the code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what the `ESC/POS` [reference manual](http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf) says on page `9` is:

Function A, `GS V m`:

```
0, 48 Executes a full cut (cuts the paper completely).

1, 49 Executes a partial cut (one point left uncut).
```

Function B, `GS V m n`:

```
65 feeds paper to (cutting position + n + vertical motion unit)
   and executes a full cut (cuts the paper completely).

66 feeds paper to (cutting position + n + vertical motion unit)
   and executes a partial cut (one point left uncut).
```

> The paper is completely or partially cut... **depending on the printer model**.

with printer model "my thermal printer" it is impossible to determine, if that printer would even support partial cutting (reading the operation manual suggested).

Comment: In function B what should be the value for n ?